# List name into variable c#

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

i'm very new as you can see in my programming, i'm making a simple program excercise. I would like to put for example the Item.price & Item.Name into Listbox2.

is it possible to put the arrayName into a variable and put it in a foreach loop? 
Just to prevent a very long IF loop or switch, or a while loop.

```
For example : 
    Array variable = Drinks;
    foreach(Product item in VARIABLE)
                        {
                            listBox2.Items.Add(item.ProductName + item.Price);
                        }
```

Ps: i already tryed with a temporary List where you put the drinkList into the Temporary list and then call it the product.Name and/or Product.price.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Product> Drinks = new List<Product>() {new Product("Coca Cola", 1.2F), new Product("Fanta", 2.0F), new Product("Sprite", 1.5F) };
    List<Product> Bread = new List<Product>() { new Product("Brown Bread", 1.2F), new Product("White Bread", 2.0F), new Product("Some otherBread", 1.5F) };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        if (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.SelectedItem) == 0)
        {
            foreach (Product item in Drinks)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            foreach (Product item in Bread)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}

public class Product
{
    private string productName;
    private float price;

    public Product(string productName, float price)
    {
        this.ProductName = productName;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return productName; }
        set { productName = value; }
    }

    public float Price
    {
       get { return price; }
       set { price = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error(s) did you get?

Comment: None, I just try to find a new way to make my code syntax smaller, and more efficient.

Comment: Since you're not looking to solve a specific problem, you may get better answers posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly but maybe you could put the type of product (drink or bread) in the struct?

```
public struct Products
{
    public string type;
    public string name;
    public double price;
}
```

You can then create the list

```
List<Products>
```

and use it in your foreach loop as you did in your example

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    // start with Bread and change if necessary.
    List<Product> products = Bread;

    if (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.SelectedItem) == 0)
    {
        //change the value of "products"
        products = Drinks;
    }

    foreach (Product item in products)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item.ProductName + item.Price);
    }

}
```